# Wordpress site making "holes" in output

Tags: php, wordpress

My page http://www.allyourpods.no/ has some odd "holes" that I cant for the life of me figure out.

I would love some help to figure out how to make it automagickly fill the site in a proper fashion.

My template-file for the start-screen looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Template
*/
 get_header(); ?>
<?php query_posts('cat='.recPodcastCategory.'&showposts=30');?>
<?php $categories = get_categories('child_of='.recPodcastCategory); ?>
<?php if($categories):  $count=0;?>
<div class="recommended">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main_recommended_main_block">

            <?php foreach($categories as $category) { if($count<30) { $count++; 
                if($count!=30) $class='recommend_block'; else $class='recommend_block_1'; ?>
                <?php if (function_exists('get_terms_meta'))
                    {
                        $cat_image = get_terms_meta($category->term_id, 'image',true);
                        $add_play_podcast = get_terms_meta($category->term_id, 'play_download',true);
                    }?>
                <div class="<?php echo $class;?>">
                    <div class="main"> 
                      <?php $play_podcast = get_post_meta($post->ID,'play_podcast',true);?>
                      <div class="view view-fifth"><?php if($cat_image):?><img src="<?php echo $cat_image;?>" alt="category image" /><?php endif;?>
                        <?php if($add_play_podcast):?>
                            <div class="mask"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id);?>" class="info">Play</a></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>



                    <?php echo substr( category_description( $category->term_id ),0,100 ) . "..."; ?>
                    </div>
            <?php } } ?>
            </div>
  </div>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(!isset($_GET['pod_category']))$class_all = ' class="active"';  ?>
<div class="clr"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If any more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: This question is a little unclear - can you please indicate what you mean by 'holes'?

Comment: If you take a look at http://www.allyourpods.no/ the first 4 podcasts are displayed normaly, but then it "jumps" over 2 spots, and it looks kinda dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this css:

```
.recommend_block:nth-child(4) {
    clear: left;
}
```

The problem is one of the first two is a little lower than the others, so it is blocking the float.

Edit: that should be

```
.recommend_block:nth-child(4n)
```

Comment: looks better, but not quite there.. ;) check it out now http://www.allyourpods.no/

Comment: .recommend_block:nth-child(4n+5), try that